# PHP / MySQL - Won't allow me to insert (or replace) right single quotation mark "’"

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a CSV file with a list of station names. Some of the names contain right single quotation mark: ’ (not a normal single quote).

I am trying to read it from the file and insert into the database. All the stations work fine, but ones with the quote get inserted into the database as `0`.

I was trying to replace it to a normal quote mark, but PHP doesn't seem to find the quote in the string.

```
if(strpos($stationName, "’") !== false){
    var_dump($stationName);
    var_dump(str_replace("’", "'", $stationName));
    die();
}
```

The code above never gets triggered. Do I need to do something with the encoding within PHP or MySQL and how should I go about fixing this?

Example of string that works fine:
`Langton Matravers, Crack Lane Bottom (N-bound)`

And example that gets inserted as `0`:
`Harman’s Cross, Wilkswood Farm Road (NW-bound)`

I am using Laravel if that makes any difference.

Thank you.

EDIT:

I've run detect decoding, which showed me that the string is in `ASCII` encoding - I believe this could be the issue, but I can't seem to change the encoding?

I run the following lines:

```
$stationName = mb_convert_encoding($stationName, "UTF-8", "ASCII");
var_dump(mb_detect_encoding($stationName));
```

And still get the output that the string is in `ASCII`?

EDIT2:

Turns out that this was issue with the actual CSV file encoding and the way the CSV library I was using (Laravel-Excel) was reading it. Adjusting the config and converting the CSV file encodings seems to have fixed the issue.

Comment: Which encoding are you using?

Comment: `UTF-8` as far as I can tell (in PHP files & database)

Comment: The string appears to be in `ASCII` according to the `mb_detect_encoding` function - but I can't seem to change it?

Comment: for what I see that single quotation is an _acute accent_. Can you check if `$stationName` has it as `ASCII` and if true then replace it?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that this was issue with the actual CSV file encoding and the way the CSV library I was using was reading it. Adjusting the config and converting the CSV file encoding to `UTF-8` seems to have fixed the issue.